# How to clean "/dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv" after YUM?

Tags: yum, disk-usage, disk-cleanup

I run Yum update on CentOS and suddenly i got disk space hike on /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv

```
[intor@alp-pp03 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            16G   12K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            16G  1.6G   15G  11% /run
tmpfs                            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv      6.9G  6.6G  286M  96% /
/dev/sda1                       488M  161M  292M  36% /boot
/dev/mapper/rootvg-opt_lv        20G   12G  8.3G  58% /opt/wildfly
/dev/mapper/rootvg-keycloak_lv  4.8G  636M  4.0G  14% /opt/keycloak
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp_lv       8.8G   37M  8.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rootvg-data_lv       50G   53M   47G   1% /data
/dev/mapper/rootvg-home_lv      997M  226M  772M  23% /home
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var_lv        13G  1.8G   11G  14% /var
/dev/mapper/rootvg-doc_lv        20G  3.6G   16G  19% /var/lib/docker
146.213.179.242:/prod01         484G  289G  196G  60% /shared
```

When i try to go to that path :

```
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Dec  9  2019 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-data_lv -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-doc_lv -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-home_lv -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-keycloak_lv -> ../dm-7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-opt_lv -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-root_lv -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Dec  9  2019 rootvg-swap_lv -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-tmp_lv -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Aug 19 01:08 rootvg-var_lv -> ../dm-3
```

When i search to that path :

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   0 Aug 19 01:08 dm-0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   1 Dec  9  2019 dm-1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   2 Aug 19 01:08 dm-2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   3 Aug 19 01:08 dm-3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   4 Aug 19 01:08 dm-4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   5 Aug 19 01:08 dm-5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   6 Aug 19 01:08 dm-6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   7 Aug 19 01:08 dm-7
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    253,   8 Aug 19 01:08 dm-8
```

I am not sure what to do and how to clean up that?

That Root (/) shows :

```
 /]$ ls
apps  boot  dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   shared  sys  usr
bin   data  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  srv     tmp  var
```

VGS:

```
/]$ vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  rootvg   2   9   0 wz--n- 129.49g <3.36g
```

[image]

du -kx | sort -rn | less

```
524568  ./usr/lib/firmware
450228  ./usr/bin
433180  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net
433180  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track
431292  ./usr/openv/lib
424724  ./usr/share
365096  ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.245.174.20220808-121330/linux-x86-64
364016  ./usr/lib/jvm
326584  ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n
326584  ./usr/openv/java/vrts
310536  ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.245.174.20220808-121330/linux-musl-x86-64
279424  ./usr/lib/modules
260984  ./usr/lib64
233548  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX
233548  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/alp-esb-app03
233548  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a
210576  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var
207204  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var/lib/docker
207204  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var/lib
199632  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX
199632  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/alp-esb-app03
199632  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a
191556  ./usr/openv/pdde
186936  ./usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.12.0.7-0.el7_9.x86_64
186316  ./usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.12.0.7-0.el7_9.x86_64/lib
177064  ./usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9.x86_64
175404  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var
171872  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var/lib/docker
171872  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var/lib
157184  ./usr/openv/java/jre
155964  ./usr/openv/java/jre/lib
148276  ./usr/libexec
143096  ./usr/lib/firmware/netronome
135592  ./usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9.x86_64/jre
135160  ./usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib
131416  ./usr/openv/netbackup/bin
124520  ./usr/share/locale
122672  ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/lib64
118188  ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64
118084  ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
115464  ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel
115360  ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel
103660  ./usr/lib/locale
103532  ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var/lib/docker/overlay
96984   ./usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins
96984   ./usr/libexec/docker
94040   ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared
93656   ./usr/src/kernels
93656   ./usr/src
85880   ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/var/lib/docker/overlay
82372   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers
82348   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers
81792   ./usr/openv/lib/shared/vddk/lib64
81792   ./usr/openv/lib/shared/vddk
81792   ./usr/openv/lib/shared
79052   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.245.174.20220808-121330/linux-x86-32
78288   ./usr/openv/pdde/pdopensource
75124   ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib
39560   ./usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server
38112   ./usr/lib/firmware/netronome/nic
36748   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python64/python3.8
36748   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python64
36728   ./usr/lib64/python2.7
36548   ./opt/VRTSpbx
35880   ./opt/VRTSpbx/lib
33800   ./usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu
33396   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.241.223.20220619-130723
32312   ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64
31976   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/en/help
31976   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/en
31444   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/811000/en/help
31444   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/811000/en
31444   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/811000
30916   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/800000/en/help
30916   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/800000/en
30916   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/800000
30756   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/810000/en/help
30756   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/810000/en
30756   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/810000
30464   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/773000/en/help
30464   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/773000/en
30464   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/773000
29872   ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/include
29304   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/771000/en/help
29304   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/771000/en
29304   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/771000
29196   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/772000/en/help
29196   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/772000/en
29196   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/772000
29164   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/770000/en/help
29164   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/770000/en
29164   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/770000
28852   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers
28348   ./usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2
28348   ./usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux
28348   ./usr/libexec/gcc
28076   ./usr/openv/netbackup/sec/at
28076   ./usr/openv/netbackup/sec
27892   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.241.223.20220619-130723/linux-x86-64
26792   ./usr/lib/firmware/netronome/bpf
26024   ./usr/lib/firmware/intel
25228   ./usr/share/vim
25216   ./usr/share/vim/vim74
24876   ./usr/lib/firmware/liquidio
24240   ./usr/lib/firmware/qcom
23840   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python64/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu
23712   ./usr/openv/lib/java
22084   ./usr/share/perl5
21640   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/datasources
21568   ./etc
21384   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/lib
21172   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/750000/en/help
21172   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/750000/en
21172   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/750000
20708   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python3.8
20680   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/600000/en/help
20680   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/600000/en
20680   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/600000
20000   ./usr/lib/firmware/qed
19172   ./usr/lib/firmware/netronome/flower
18992   ./usr/openv/lib/vxfi
18984   ./usr/openv/lib/vxfi/providers
18916   ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/bin
18832   ./usr/share/backgrounds
18624   ./usr/lib/firmware/qcom/sdm845
18464   ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64/include
18408   ./usr/lib64/perl5
17992   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net
17984   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net
17836   ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/alp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/_track_log_root_
16924   ./usr/openv/netbackup/sec/at/lib
16736   ./usr/lib/firmware/brcm
16660   ./usr/openv/java/jre/lib/amd64/server
16512   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/710000/en/help
16512   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/710000/en
16512   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/710000
15864   ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vpfs
15604   ./usr/openv/pdde/vpfs
15056   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/650000/en/help
15056   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/650000/en
15056   ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/650000
15032   ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/include/linux
14436   ./usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
14436   ./usr/lib/python2.7
14384   ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/bin/.bin
14348   ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/ppp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/_track_log_root_
14056   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/media
14052   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/media
13944   ./usr/openv/netbackup/bin/support
13904   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/datasources/prometheus
13756   ./usr/share/nmap
13556   ./usr/lib64/samba
12996   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/res/dsruntime/python3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
12904   ./usr/lib/udev
12892   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python64/python3.8/lib-dynload
12748   ./usr/lib64/dyninst
12732   ./usr/openv/lib/ost-plugins
12184   ./usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d
12176   ./usr/lib/firmware/ath10k
12160   ./usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
12104   ./usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1
11808   ./usr/lib/firmware/dpaa2/mc
11808   ./usr/lib/firmware/dpaa2
11540   ./usr/lib/firmware/mellanox
11488   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/net
11420   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/net
11248   ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/res/dsruntime/python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
11120   ./usr/openv/lib/map
11096   ./usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
11068   ./usr/openv/netbackup/sec/at/bin
10944   ./usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto
10468   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/fs
10456   ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/fs
10208   ./usr/share/man/man1
10080   ./usr/lib/firmware/bnx2x
10028   ./usr/openv/lib/map/rvp
10004   ./usr/lib/systemd
9940    ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/700000/en/help
9940    ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/700000/en
9940    ./usr/openv/java/vrts/nbvsm_l10n/700000
9700    ./usr/share/i18n
9660    ./usr/openv/pdde/vpfs/lib
9600    ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/ppp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/opt
9580    ./usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/Encode
9296    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/app
9196    ./usr/share/cracklib
9168    ./usr/include
9004    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet
9000    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet
8820    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/tools
8800    ./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2
8800    ./usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux
8800    ./usr/lib/gcc
8776    ./usr/share/man/man3
8760    ./usr/lib/firmware/i915
8732    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/tools/lib64
8704    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi
8700    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/scsi
8700    ./usr/lib/firmware/mrvl
8680    ./etc/udev
8516    ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64/include/linux
8404    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm
8404    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu
8404    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm
8404    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/gpu
8400    ./usr/libexec/postfix
8320    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/res/dsruntime/python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip
8292    ./usr/openv/lib/ost-plugins/zapi
8020    ./usr/libexec/git-core
7940    ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap103a/ppp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/opt/wildfly
7884    ./usr/share/hwdata
7880    ./usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.302.b08-0.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/ext
7768    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python3.8/site-packages
7732    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/datasources/statsd
7572    ./usr/lib/firmware/radeon
7556    ./usr/openv/java/jre/lib/ext
7556    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net
7492    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/sound
7492    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/sound
7464    ./usr/lib64/gconv
7412    ./usr/share/httpd
7084    ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/drivers
7048    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/res/dsruntime/python3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor
7040    ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/arch
6988    ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64
6852    ./usr/share/perl5/pod
6616    ./usr/lib/firmware/mediatek
6488    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
6484    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
6404    ./usr/lib/gconv
6396    ./usr/share/i18n/locales
6380    ./usr/share/vim/vim74/lang
6320    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography
6232    ./etc/selinux
6224    ./etc/selinux/targeted
6180    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat
6152    ./opt/DDMI
6112    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vpfs/livemount
5968    ./usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax
5896    ./usr/share/httpd/noindex
5880    ./usr/share/httpd/noindex/css
5836    ./usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/fonts
5708    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
5676    ./usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES
5676    ./usr/share/locale/de
5660    ./usr/share/perl5/unicore
5620    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.245.174.20220808-121330/any
5556    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdopensource/bin
5548    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python3.8/site-packages/pip
5544    ./usr/share/mime
5508    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdopensource/bin/.bin
5504    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.241.223.20220619-130723/any
5468    ./usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES
5468    ./usr/share/locale/uk
5424    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/sound/pci
5424    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/sound/pci
5336    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.231.288.20220218-170442/any
5336    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.231.288.20220218-170442
5336    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.231.284.20220209-201902/any
5336    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.231.284.20220209-201902
5336    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.231.245.20220112-085307/any
5336    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.231.245.20220112-085307
5320    ./usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
5320    ./usr/share/locale/es
5316    ./usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats
5316    ./usr/share/microcode_ctl
5304    ./usr/openv/pdde/pdshared/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vpfs/actions
5300    ./usr/share/fonts
5296    ./usr/share/fonts/dejavu
5288    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.229.195.20211211-144136/any
5288    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.229.195.20211211-144136
5248    ./usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
5248    ./usr/share/locale/fr
5240    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.227.157.20211116-102348/any
5240    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.227.157.20211116-102348
5220    ./usr/share/zoneinfo
5204    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.225.159.20211013-185604/any
5204    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.225.159.20211013-185604
5140    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.223.123.20210929-151009/any
5140    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.223.123.20210929-151009
5140    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.223.105.20210824-140926/any
5140    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.223.105.20210824-140926
5128    ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/include/uapi
5120    ./usr/share/info
5048    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.221.132.20210728-085542/any
5048    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/bin/1.221.132.20210728-085542
5040    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/plugins
4924    ./usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES
4924    ./usr/share/locale/sv
4840    ./usr/share/dict
4832    ./usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel
4820    ./usr/share/microcode_ctl/ucode_with_caveats/intel/intel-ucode
4796    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/media/usb
4796    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/media/usb
4724    ./usr/share/man/overrides
4704    ./usr/share/man/man3p
4648    ./usr/lib/firmware/cxgb4
4628    ./usr/share/man/man8
4576    ./usr/lib/kbd
4528    ./usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
4528    ./usr/share/locale/ru
4436    ./usr/include/linux
4412    ./usr/openv/pdde/vpfs/bin
4376    ./usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8.5
4332    ./opt/dynatrace/oneagent/agent/plugin/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor
4264    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/media
4248    ./usr/openv/netbackup/track/nofetnbma100.cosng.net/nofetnbap102a/ppp-esb-app03/EVRY-FILE-LAN-UNIX/opt
4236    ./usr/openv/pdde/vpfs/bin/.bin
4228    ./usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/include/uapi/linux
4196    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet
4168    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64/kernel/net
4160    ./usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES
4160    ./usr/share/locale/pl
4000    ./usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES
4000    ./usr/share/locale/ja
3984    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/infiniband
3984    ./usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/infiniband
3980    ./usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES
3980    ./usr/share/locale/zh_CN
3920    ./usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES
3920    ./usr/share/locale/vi
and much more...
```

TREE:

```
/]$ tree -LP 1 /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv
.
├── apps
├── boot
├── data
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── shared
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
└── var

18 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138634/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-romeo-ninov).

Comment: Wait for the end, otherwise we can't give advice where is the diskspace

Comment: But i think logs are quite big and tried to du -skx /* > something.txt <--- this is not working either

Comment: they are not. Just wait. You can filter error message by: `du -skx /* 2>/dev/null`

Comment: `du -skx /*` will match `/shared` which is a large NFS mount, causing the command to waste a lot of effort on a irrelevant filesystem. Try `du -kx | sort -rn | less` instead.

Comment: @telcoM, IMHO no. this is the idea of `-x`

Comment: If you give a mount point as an explicit parameter (which happens when the shell expands the wildcard) then `du -skx` will summarize that mounted filesystem but not any of it's submounts.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: For du -skx /* 2>/dev/null ; it retuns result like "1655344 /run" <-- Is this bytes?

Comment: @telcoM: Reg du -kx | sort -rn | less ---> It retuns size like 5322136 ./usr
2520300 ./usr/openv
1352188 ./usr/lib... Is it bytes , i need to convert to g?

Comment: @fatherazrael, no in kilobytes, and you can ignore `/run` , `/dev`, `/sys`

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Some attached result to du -kx | sort -rn | less ; rest queries are still on

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I have added output of TREE. Do you think i should look into those 4 only?

Comment: You can try to reduce some filesystems like `/var` and `/var/lib/docker` by few gigabytes and use them to extend `root-lv`. Or add another disk, add it to VG and extend LV

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I am not server guy actually and a developer, so not sure if i can do these things by myself? What to follow and what not. And i like idea why /var and /var/lib/docker are using so much

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Any idea what can be temprarily done and with which directory -> /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv      6.9G  6.9G  220K 100% /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do these actions to extend `root` filesystem, but further steps are complicated and will be better sysadmin to do them.

All command to be executed as `root` user!

```
lvextend -L+1G /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv
resize2fs /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv
```

In case of `XFS` you should use command

```
xfs_growfs /
```

this will extend the filesystem by 1GB, but for more will be good to "steal" from other filesystems as discussed in comments.

Comment: When execute second command it says:

resize2fs /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: First command was success:
lvextend -L+1G /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv
  Size of logical volume rootvg/root_lv changed from 6.84 GiB (1750 extents) to 7.84 GiB (2006 extents).
  Logical volume root_lv successfully resized.

Comment: But "df -h" shows same -> /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv      6.9G  5.7G  1.2G  83% /

Comment: @fatherazrael, what is your filesystem of root?

Comment: Sorry but finding command for same. No Sysadmin available so looking for workarounds.

Comment: try `mount |grep root_lv`

Comment: Thanks. It says -> /dev/mapper/rootvg-root_lv on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)

Comment: @fatherazrael, did you read entire answer? `xfs_growfs /`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Is it safe to run in production? Hope not need any kind of restarts etc.?

Comment: @fatherazrael, there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. It worked for now and you saved an important activity we are having in production today. No one was available and it could be mess :)